# PreparedStatement very slow, but manual query quick

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, ofbiz

I have a preparedstatement from a framework as followed:

```
SELECT OH.ORDER_ID, MAX(OS.STATUS_DATETIME) FROM public.ORDER_HEADER OH, public.ORDER_STATUS OS WHERE ((OH.ORDER_ID = OS.ORDER_ID AND OH.STATUS_ID = ? AND OS.STATUS_ID = ?)) GROUP BY OH.ORDER_
ID HAVING (MAX(OS.STATUS_DATETIME) <= ?) ORDER BY OH.ORDER_ID ASC
```

OrderHeader has 300 000 rows, OrderStatus has roughly 5-6 million.
All queried fields have an index on them. The database is Postgres 9.1

```
SELECT OH.ORDER_ID, MAX(OS.STATUS_DATETIME) FROM ORDER_HEADER OH INNER JOIN ORDER_STATUS OS 
    ON ((OH.ORDER_ID = OS.ORDER_ID AND OH.STATUS_ID = 'ORDER_PARTIALLY_RECEIVED' AND OS.STATUS_ID = 'ORDER_PARTIALLY_RECEIVED'))
     GROUP BY OH.ORDER_ID HAVING (MAX(OS.STATUS_DATETIME) <= '2015-01-27 00:00:00') ORDER BY OH.ORDER_ID ASC
```

This is the query string when the parameters are substitued in.

Running the query from Java, as a PreparedStatement and parameters set in there is making the query to run for minutes (5-6 minutes).
When i run the SQL manually, it takes 10 seconds.
How is this possible, how can i explain it?

Comment: Post your java code. From your description the problem is on java side.

Comment: Also, make sure that you're executing exactly the same query (as shown by logging from the DB side) and not one that's subtly different.

Comment: Those two statements look quite different. Why does the second one have an inner join?

Answer (score 4):

Prepared statements are optimized without knowledge of actual parameters. In PostgreSQL 9.1 a prepared statements are optimized only for most common values. When prepared statements is slow, then you have to use a dynamic SQL. PostgreSQL has nice API - parametric queries - it is some between prepared statements and usual queries - It is safe against SQL injection, and it is immune against a problems with blind optimization.

Comment: what do you mean by use dynamic SQL?

Comment: @david - it is common name for statements executed via `EXECUTE` statement on Postgres or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` on Oracle. The query are formatted at last time - at runtime, and any time can be different - at runtime are created from strings - dynamic queries

Answer (score 2):

If the result set is large - PreparedStatement could work slower, because default "fetchSize" is only 10.
Try to set bigger fetchSize for this query.
More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/resltse5.htm

And specialy for Postgres here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html

Comment: The actual query is slow (it is running at the db, not the resultset processing).

Answer (score 0):

If you use preparedStatements,you must identify paramter type . you can explain the sql.
e.g
uid type is integer

  `explain analyse select * from users where uid in (200,500,800);
  PREPARE fooplan (int, int, int) AS
  select *
  from users
  where uid in ($1, $2, $3);
  explain analyse EXECUTE fooplan(200, 500, 800);
  PREPARE fooplan1 (numeric, numeric, numeric) AS
  select *
  from users
  where uid in ($1, $2, $3);
  explain analyse EXECUTE fooplan1(200, 500, 800);`

[image]